# Extract Real Numbers from a string in Java

Tags: java

I'd like to extract real numbers from a string in java. The string is circle(5.5) and I'd like to extract the 5.5. I think there is a way to do this with regex? but I'm not sure. Is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367381/extract-numbers-from-a-string-java) thread and especially the last answer

Comment: that only handles integers. When i tried it it returned 5 5 is there a way to get it to return 5.5?

Comment: did you use this regex `(([0-9]+.[0-9]*)|([0-9]*.[0-9]+)|([0-9]+))`

Comment: that printed (5

then .5 on the next line

Answer (score 0):

You need to make pattern for number then parse it in double or float gives what you want.
see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367381/extract-numbers-from-a-string-java)