# Extracting phone number from string

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to extract phone number in java from the given String i.e. the phone number can be anywhere in the String like `[bla bla]TELEPHONE NUMBER[bla bla]`.Now I want to extract this telephone number in another String.

While using the

```
 matcher.matches()
```

it returns me true or false but I am not getting the phone number which it gets extracted.

Comment: OK, so tell us what you think a phone number looks like.

Comment: `matches()` will return true if it matches the whole string. Use `find` and capture `group` to get the substring

Comment: Check this post over stackoverflow 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367381/extract-numbers-from-a-string-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]+([0-9]+).*");
Matcher m = p.matcher("Testing123Testing");

if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Comment: I don't think that 123 is a phone number.

Your regex matches single numbers too...

Comment: 123 is just an example.it will take account 0-9

Comment: Yeah but he is trying to find phone numbers which is different then just looking for number in a String

Comment: Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]+([0-9]+).*"); where you can make your desire pattern

Comment: I tried this:Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("^\\(?(\\d{3})\\)?[- ]?(\\d{3})[- ]?(\\d{4})$+").matcher("abc (213) 240-7838");
        if(matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));

        },but not working

Comment: Of course... your regex does not match letters... remove `^` and `$` and it should work. `\(?(\\d{3})\)?[- ]?(\\d{3})[- ]?(\\d{4})`

Comment: Matches following phone numbers:    (123)456-7890,         123-456-7890,1234567890, (123)-456-7890                         String expression = "^\\(?(\\d{3})\\)?[- ]?(\\d{3})[- ]?(\\d{4})$";  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression);

Comment: Possible duplicate answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237061/using-regular-expressions-to-extract-a-value-in-java/237068#237068

Comment: Haha, where I live, 123 is indeed a phone number!

Answer (score 4):

To find number in **any** given format You can use use [libphonenumber](https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/) and [findNumbers](http://libphonenumber.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/i18n/phonenumbers/PhoneNumberUtil.html#findNumbers(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.String)) function.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your regular expression works as it should, you should take a look at [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) regex  tutorial from Sun.