# Find all numbers in the String

Tags: java, string, algorithm

For example, I have input String: "*qwerty1qwerty2*";

As Output I would like have *[1,2]*.

My current implementation below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String inputString = args[0];
        String digitStr = "";
        List<Integer> digits = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++) {
            if (Character.isDigit(inputString.charAt(i))) {
                digitStr += inputString.charAt(i);
            } else {
                if (!digitStr.isEmpty()) {
                    digits.add(Integer.parseInt(digitStr));
                    digitStr = "";
                }
            }
        }
        if (!digitStr.isEmpty()) {
            digits.add(Integer.parseInt(digitStr));
            digitStr = "";
        }

        for (Integer i : digits) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

But after double check I dislake couple points:

1. Some lines of code repeat twice.
2. I use List. I think it is not very good idea, better using array.

So, What do you think?

Could you please provide any advice?

Comment: you are not allowed to use regex?

Comment: My thoughts exactly as this would be pretty trivial using regular expressions and `String#replaceAll(...)`

Comment: For code reviews please use the code review stack exchange site :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367381/extract-numbers-from-a-string-java

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Use replaceAll:

```
String str = "qwerty1qwerty2";      
str = str.replaceAll("[^0-9]+", " ");
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(str.trim().split(" ")));
```

Output:

```
[1, 2]
```

**[EDIT]**

If you want to include `-` a.e minus, add `-?`:

```
String str = "qwerty-1qwerty-2 455 f0gfg 4";      
str = str.replaceAll("[^-?0-9]+", " "); 
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(str.trim().split(" ")));
```

Output:

```
[-1, -2, 455, 0, 4]
```

---

*Description*

```
[^-?0-9]+
```

- `+` Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed
- `-?` One of the characters “-?”
- `0-9` A character in the range between “0” and “9”

Comment: You should put `str = str.replaceAll("[^-?0-9]+", " ");` to match negative numbers.

Comment: @JelledeFries, well, who knows if `-` represented as *minus* or *hyphen*.

Comment: @JelledeFries I edited my answer with "-" support if needed

Comment: @MaximShoustin You are right, it depends on the problem. I had a problem that required the recognition of negative numbers.

Comment: But the above solution doesn't seem to work for "0.0". Any suggestions on how to get this fixed too?

Comment: @kris123456 well, 0.0 is not number. suppose u need a pattern something like `[^-?0-9]+.[0-9]+`

Answer (score 6):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

...

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+"); 
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("test1string1337thingie");

// Find all matches
while (matcher.find()) { 
  // Get the matching string  
  String match = matcher.group();
}
```

Is one regexp solution.

Comment: Actually, let me check if the pattern is correct usage here, just quickly googled and improvised. Haven't used java nor regexp in a while.

Comment: Yes, it matches. Just add results to some container of your choice.

Answer (score 2):

try this code

```
String s = "qwerty1qwerty2";
for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
{
   if(Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i)))
   System.out.print(s.charAt(i)+"  ");
}
```

Comment: And what about this line: "123fgfgfgfgfgfgv5kkk60". Expected result is [123, 5, 60].

Comment: modified code


int len = s.length();

        for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
        {

                if(Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i)))
                { 
                    System.out.print(s.charAt(i));

                    i++;

                    while(i<len&&Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i)))
                    {
                        System.out.print(s.charAt(i));

                        i++;

                    }
                    System.out.print("  ");
                }

        }

Comment: @user1831612 Edit your answer; don't try to stuff code into a comment--it's illegible.