# Convert Date String to Date form

Tags: java, string, date

I have this String which I want to convert in Date form like 2013-06-06

```
 "/Date(1370257470183+0530)/"
```

If anybody have Idea , How to do this programmatically please help me

Regards.

Comment: What does the + signify?

Comment: I think +0530 indicates the GMT

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573250/android-how-can-i-convert-string-to-date)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String dateString = "/Date(1370257470183+0530)/";

    String longString = dateString.substring(6, dateString.indexOf('+'));
    String gmtString = dateString.substring(dateString.indexOf('+'), dateString.indexOf(')'));

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(gmtString));
    Date date = new Date(Long.parseLong(longString));
    System.out.println(format.format(date));

}
```

- Extract number value by getting substring
- Extract GMT string
- Create a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)
- Format the timezone with the GMT string
- Create a Date object from the first string
- Pass the date to the formatter (return String)
- Do something with that returned String

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I coded. But before that you have to extract the timezone and the millisecond time so that you can create the Object. I think that you can do just doing some string operations upon the string.

```
Date date = new Date(1370257470183l); // here is your time
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+0530"));   // here is your timezone
String formattedDate = formatter.format(date);
System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `java.util.Date` class and then use `SimpleDateFormat` to format the Date.

```
Date date=new Date(millis);
```

Reference: [How to convert currentTimeMillis to a date in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8237193/java-convert-milliseconds-to-date)

The input represents time in milliseconds from epoch ( Jan 1, 1970 GMT)
by the way your input represents a date of 3rd June 2013

Answer (score 0):

First you will have to search the String for the numeric values, link here: 
[Search a String for Numerics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13440506/java-find-all-numbers-in-the-string-need-check)

Then you want to turn the numeric value into a date. For that use SimpleDateFormat" link here:[Oracle SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)