# Numbers from string

Tags: java, string, for-loop

```
public void check(String str){
    for(int i =0; i<str.length(); i++){
    //Print only the numbers    
    }
}
```

In that for loop I want to be able to look through the string and find just the first two numbers.  How do I do that?

Example:

```
str= 1 b 3 s 4
```

Print:
    1 3

Comment: Check out the `Character` class.

Comment: '1 b 23 s 5' should print what? '1 23' or '1 2'? Does the spacing matter? Or you can just print 12?

Comment: Related work

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367381/extract-numbers-from-a-string-java

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13440506/java-find-all-numbers-in-the-string-need-check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for numbers that are more than one digit.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public void check(String str) {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(str);
    for(int n = 0; n < 2 && m.find(); n++)  {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

`\d+` (written in a `String` literal as `"\\d+"`) is a regular expression that matches one or more digits.

`m.find()` finds the next match, returning whether it found the match.

`m.group()` returns the matched substring.

Comment: Do this go in the for loop?

Comment: @user243872, I added the method signature to make this more clear.

Comment: @user243872, do you have an extra for loop?

Comment: oh haha ya.. my bad.  But what if the string sent in is just letters. example: aaaaa

Comment: @user243872, then it is impossible to print two numbers. What do you want to happen in that case? An exception? Printing as many numbers as are present, but no more than two?

Comment: I just want it to be able to get the first two numbers and if there are no numbers in the string to just skip it and not do anything with it.