# Separate number from a string

Tags: java

I want to get the numbers of a given string and I used the code as below

```
String sample = "7011WD";
    String output = "";
    for (int index = 0; index < sample.length(); index++)
    {
        if (Character.isDigit(sample.charAt(index)))
        {
            char aChar = sample.charAt(index);
            output = output + aChar;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("output :" + output);
```

**The Result is:**
output :7011

Is there any simple way to get the output?

Comment: That code seems to work. What's the question?

Comment: Check with existing posts like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367381/extract-numbers-from-a-string-java

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there any simple way to get the output

May be you could use a regex `\\D+` (`D` is anything which is not a digit , `+` means one or more occurence), and then [String#replaceAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,java.lang.String%29) all non-digits with empty string:

```
String sample = "7011WD";
String output = sample.replaceAll("\\D+","");
```

**Though remember**, using regex is not efficient at all . Also , this regex will remove the decimal points too !

You need to use [Integer#parseInt(output)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) or [Long#parseLong(output)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong%28java.lang.String%29) to get the primitive `int` or `long` respectively.

---

You can also use [Google's Guava CharMatcher](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html). Specify the range using [inRange()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html#inRange%28char,char%29) and return the characters from that range in sequence as a `String` using [retainFrom()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html#retainFrom%28java.lang.CharSequence%29).

Comment: If you're actually looking to get an integer, use Integer.parseInt(output)

Comment: @RobertKotcher Will add that !

Comment: I thought `\D` matches non-digit chars, could clarify please.

Comment: Yes `replaceAll()` non-digits with empty string !

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use ASCII to do this

```
String sample = "7011WD";
String output = "";
for (int index = 0; index < sample.length(); index++)
{

        char aChar = sample.charAt(index);
        if(int(aChar)>=48 && int(aChar)<= 57)
        output = output + aChar;
    }
}

System.out.println("output :" + output);
```

Comment: OP asked for a simpler way to solve this problem, I'm not sure this follows those guidelines.