# Java Regexp does not match exact number of matches

Tags: java, regex

I've got the following string:

```
0 days 00 hour 20 min 51 sec
```

I would like to extract all the numbers from it using Java's Regular Expressions:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d){1,2} days (\\d){2} hour (\\d){2} min (\\d){2} sec");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher("0 days 00 hour 20 min 51 sec");
```

To my surprise `m.group(4)` returns 1 and not 51. The same goes for `m.group(2)` which returns 0 and not 00

I found this confusing since {n} should match exactly n occurrences of the preceding expression, or not ?

Comment: The thing is that when you have repeated capture groups (e.g. `(abc)*`), only the last match will be 'saved'. This is why you need `(\\d{2})`.

Comment: I feel this is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367381/extract-numbers-from-a-string-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You likely wanted to catch both digits in the same group:

```
"(\\d{1,2}) days (\\d{2}) hour (\\d{2}) min (\\d{2}) sec"
```

---

This is what the original expression would do.

```
0 days 00 hour 20 min 51 sec
```

- `(\d){1,2}` matches 0, places it in group 1
- `(\d){2}` matches 0, places it in group 2, matches 0 again, places it in group 2
- `(\d){2}` matches 2, places it in group 3, matches 0, places it in group 3
- `(\d){2}` matches 5, places it in group 4, matches 1, places it in group 4

You now have:

- 0 in group 1
- 0 in group 2
- 0 in group 3
- 1 in group 4

Answer (score 3):

The `{...}` structures should be inside the `(...)` parenthesis, e.g.

```
Pattern.compile("(\\d{1,2}) days (\\d{2}) hour (\\d{2}) min (\\d{2}) sec");
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `(\\d{1,2})` You're leaving the repetition operator out of the group.