# How to verify the number of rows present in page using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have a page where the number of rows are present and it is dynamic.
I want to verify the text which is showing 1 to 18 rows are showing.
But it should not be hard coded.
It should return the actual number of rows present.

Comment: If you are actually hoping to get an answer, then I strongly recommend that you add the following: 1. The code that you have implemented so far. 2. The language that you are using (if not obvious from your code). 3. The URL of the web-page that you are trying to access, or at least the relevant piece of HTML within that web-page.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mentioned language i giving you a example in C# you do the following

```
IWebElement location = Browser.Driver.FindElement(table locator));
                ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> totalRow = location.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));
```

will give the number of rows present

```
totalRowtotalRow.Count;
```

If you some more help let me know

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar example using Java:

```
int rowCount = 0;
rowCount = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table/tr").size();
System.out.println("number of rows: "+rowCount);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should grab the WebElement that displays the count of **showing 1 to 18 rows** and try capturing the numbers from the string using regex and store it in a variable.

For extracting numbers, you can refer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/2367418/2482430

Later you can find all available elements based on suitable XPath or CSS Locator as below
`List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table//tr"));`

or

`List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssLocator("table tr"));`

Finally you can do the Assert as below,

`Assert.assertTrue(elements.size() == totalRowsCount);`