# Read only numbers from scanner

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

Imagine there is Scanner passes any String input such as "11 22 a b 22" and the method should calculate the total sum of all of the numbers (55 for the mentiond example). I've coded something here but I'm not able to skip strings. Could anyone help me with that?

```
System.out.println("Please enter any words and/or numbers: ");
String kbdInput = kbd.nextLine();
Scanner input = new Scanner(kbdInput);
addNumbers(input);  

public static void addNumbers(Scanner input) {
    double sum = 0;
    while (input.hasNextDouble()) {
        double nextNumber = input.nextDouble();
        sum += nextNumber;
    }
    System.out.println("The total sum of the numbers from the file is " + sum);

}
```

Comment: This is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367381/extract-numbers-from-a-string-java - that solution will likely work for you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To be able to bypass non-numeric input, you need to have your `while` loop look for any tokens still on the stream, not just `double`s.

```
while (input.hasNext())
```

Then, inside, the `while` loop, see if the next token is a `double` with `hasNextDouble`.  If not, you still need to consume the token with a call to `next()`.

```
if (input.hasNextDouble())
{
   double nextNumber = input.nextDouble();
   sum += nextNumber;
}
else
{
   input.next();
}
```