# Extract numbers from String in Java

Tags: java, regex, numbers

Referring to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367381/extract-numbers-from-a-string-java). I have a new Problem. I want to extract the last two appearing numbers (longitude/latitude) from a String.

I use the approach from the referenced answer. A simple example where the error occures can be found here:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "St. Louis (38.6389, -90.342)"; 

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?[\\d\\.]+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

    while(m.find()){
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
}
```

Console output is as following:

```
.
38.6389
-90.342
```

The Problem appears to be the "." in "St. Louis". Can someone help me to solve this issue in a nice way?

Thanks a lot for every answer/comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your regex like below,

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?");
```

`(?:\\.\\d+)?` at the last would make the decimal part as optional.

Comment: This fails to catch `.9`, which is also a common way to write 0.9, Including in java's syntax

Comment: then this `"-?\\d*(?:\\.\\d+)?"`, but i think `.9` would be written as `0.9`

Answer (score 3):

```
[-+]?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?
```

Use [this](https://regex101.com/r/wU7sQ0/38) for floating numbers and integers.

#### The Problem appears to be the "." in "St. Louis"

Thats because of `-?[\\d\\.]+` `[]` the `character class`.It can match any character defined inside class.

Comment: This fails to catch `.9`, which is also a common way to write 0.9, Including in java's syntax

Comment: @amit i guess that should be clarified with OP if he wants it or not

Comment: Why wouldn't he? It's a legitimate writing, maybe the OP should also explicitly clarify if he wants to include the digit 5 as well?

Comment: @amit because these are `longitudes and latitudes`.i m not very sure there these numbers can appear or not

Comment: If 0.9 can appear, so does .9

Answer (score 0):

A regex like `-?\d*(?:\.\d+)?` causes the engine to find zero-width matches everywhere. A better approach is to simply use alternation to require that *either* there is a dot with numbers *or* one or more numbers after which a dot with more numbers is optional:

```
-?(?:\.\d+|\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/nfGEWfnJ46yalmu_)

In Java you need to escape this like so:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?(?:\\.\\d+|\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)");
```

Alternatively, you could add a lookahead that requires that there is at least one number somewhere:

```
-?(?=\.?\d)\d*(?:\.\d+)?
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/WWMsrI7tPrWre9ar)