# How to get text from inside tag use selenium webdriver java?

Tags: java, selenium

***Here my HTML:-***

```
<li id="li1">
  <div>
    <p class="font11 metadata_value">0 Views | 14 Downloads</p>
    <p class="font11 metadata_value">639.78 MB</p>
</div>                      
</li>
```

I want to get 639.78

How to get use selenium java?

I wrote this code but not working.

`System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//[@id='li1']/div[1]/p[2]")).getText());`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37201909/edit) your question and add your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the text using the code  :

```
String text = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("p.font11.metadata_value")).getText()
```

The variable *text* will contain **639.78 MB** value .
You can extract **639.78** from the text in several ways like :

```
text.split("\\s+")[0] // this will return 639.78
```

OR

you can use regular expressions for extracting number like `([0-9.]*).*`

you can take help from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367381/how-to-extract-numbers-from-a-string-and-get-an-array-of-ints) if you are using regex

For having multiple `<p>` like :

`<li id="li1"> <div> <p class="font11 metadata_value">0 Views | 14 Downloads</p> <p class="font11 metadata_value">639.78 MB</p> </div> </li>`,

you can use **xpath** to get the text values.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='li1']/div/p[1]")).getText() // for first <p>

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='li1']/div/p[2]")).getText() //for second <p>

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='li1']/div/p[3]")).getText() // for third <p>

and so on ..
```

After getting the text of `<p>` tag , you can extract the info using some regular expression.

Comment: Its working fine but i if there is two <p> what will do ?? i want second <p> text only?

Comment: <li id="li1">
  <div>
    <p class="font11 metadata_value">0 Views | 14 Downloads</p>
    <p class="font11 metadata_value">639.78 MB</p>
</div>                      
</li>   how to get second <p> text

Comment: you can add index in xpath like this  : By.xpath("//li[@id='li1']/div[1]/p") , By.xpath("//li[@id='li1']/div[1]/p") and so on ..

Answer (score 1):

Using For loop on all available text using css selector, Can print it.

```
public void verifrytext(String inputext)
{
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
    List <WebElement> text = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".font11 metadata_value"));

   for(int i=0; i< text.size(); i++)
   {
     if(text.get(i).getText().equalsIgnoreCase(inputext))
     {
       System.out.println(text.get(i).getText());
     }   
   }
}
```

Comment: FYI: gettext() should be getText()

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Selenium Tutorial](http://software-testing-tutorials-automation.blogspot.de/2014/01/locating-web-element-by-classname-in.html):

```
public class Mytest1 { 
//To open Firefox browser 
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 

@Before public void beforetest() { 
//To Maximize Browser Window 
driver.manage().window().maximize(); 
//To Open URL In browser 
driver.get("http://only-testing-blog.blogspot.in/2013/11/new-test.html"); 
} 



@After public void aftertest() { 
   driver.quit(); 
   } 

   @Test public void test() { 
   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

   //READ
   String datentime = driver.findElement(By.className("metadata_value")).getText();
   //WRITE
   driver.findElement(By.className("metadata_value")).sendKeys("SOME_STRING");

   }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regular expression to remove the text around the number and then parse it:

```java
String text = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#li1 > div > p:nth-child(2)")).getText();
Float value = Float.parseFloat(text.replaceFirst(".*?([\\d.]+).*", "$1"));
```