# Match the groups of numbers from String

Tags: java, regex, selenium

I am working on java and I wanted to extract groups of matchings from a string, but I wonder how can I match the groups of numbers from a string.

For example, the string is "qwerty**123834**asdf**3486**dq123", I want to extract **123834** as the first group of matching and **3486** as a second group, then I need to save the first group in one variable and the second one in another variable, 123 is not required. I must do it with a grouping as 1st group of matching and 2nd, because the amount of numbers in group changes, thus I cannot take just substring.

I tried ([0-9])+, but it extracted all numbers, but I want to groups of matchings. Is it possible to do sth like this, ([0-9])+{1} to extract **123834** and ([0-9])+{2} to extract **3486**

Comment: 12334 ? Are you sure ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367381/how-to-extract-numbers-from-a-string-and-get-an-array-of-ints

Comment: @Tushar thanks, I edited my post

Comment: "I tried ([0-9])+, but it gave all matchings, but I want to have groups of matchings." Please elaborate. It's unclear what you mean.

Comment: I have edited my post and I hope, it is much clearer now.

Comment: How is this question a duplicate of that??
Well here is what you need. `[^0-9]+([0-9]+)[^0-9]+([0-9]+)[^0-9]+.*`

This will match with two groups of numbers. Can be shorter if you use the greedy flag. Then you don't need the [^0-9] parts.

Comment: @Torge Thank you very much, it worked, but since no one helped, I found another way to solve this issue: `word = word.replaceAll("[^0-9]+", " ");
        String[] array = word.trim().split(" ");
        String firstNumber=array[0];
        String secondNumber=array[1];`