# How to split a string with recurrent characters in java

Tags: java, string, split

I'm trying to split a string of the following format (with x possible numbers in the lists) into two different strings :

"9 7 20 -3 4” “1 2 0 -6"

I know how to split a string, but only by one character (a space for example)

I wouldn't know what to do to split this into two strings by their quotation marks.

And after having split these into two different strings, I don't know how to split the lists themselves into an array of numbers (since there is an x number of possible numbers).

Comment: So, you want to get `"9 7 20 -3 4"` and `"1 2 0 -6"` from `"9 7 20 -3 4” “1 2 0 -6"` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Comment: what do you want to get in the end? an array of numbers?

Comment: Yes I do want to end up with an array of numbers

Comment: Also, it's not a duplicate : the post you suggest is only for one character. I'm having problem splitting at multiple quotation marks

Comment: I would use regex : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367381/how-to-extract-numbers-from-a-string-and-get-an-array-of-ints  once you understand it you can manipulate strings so easy ;)

Comment: Is `” “` typed mistakenly instead of `" "`? In other word, are `” “` two double quotations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do You mean to split with this regex `”\\s+“`:

```
String str = "9 7 20 -3 4” “1 2 0 -6";
String spl[] = str.split("”\\s+“");
```

Outputs

```
[9 7 20 -3 4, 1 2 0 -6]
```