# How to use pattern or matcher for replacing pattern in string?

Tags: java, android, string

I have a String like

> "Hello @[---68---] and @[---64---] and d@[---102---] . how are you
>   all?"

Here I want to **EXTRACT** numbers/strings that starts with "**@[---**" and ends with "**---]**", which here is 68,64,102 and so on.

How could I make a pattern/regex for it? Any help would be appreciated.
I tried a few solutions from [Pattern](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern) and [Matcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Matcher)

Comment: Try this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/2367418/9868485

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this:

```
 Pattern MY_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]");
        Matcher m = MY_PATTERN.matcher("Hello @[---68---] and @[---64---] and d@[---102---]");
         while (m.find()) {
           String s = m.group(1);
           System.out.println(s.split("---")[1]);
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code  to  get numbers form `String`:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexExamples {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("numFound=\"([0-9]+)\"");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("");

        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```