# In Java with regular expressions, how to capture numbers from a string with unknown length?

Tags: java, regex, expression, grouping, capture

My regular expression looks like this: `"[a-zA-Z]+[ \t]*(?:,[ \t]*(\\d+)[ \t]*)*"`

I can match the lines with this, but I don't know how to capture the numbers,I think it has to do something with grouping.

For example: from the string `"asd  , 5    ,2,6   ,8"`, how to capture the numbers 5 2 6 and 8?

A few more examples:

```
sdfs6df -> no capture

fdg4dfg, 5 -> capture 5

fhhh3      ,     6,8    , 7 -> capture 6 8 and 7

asdasd1,4,2,7 -> capture 4 2 and 7
```

So I can continue my work with these numbers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any constraints ? Or just get the numbers ?

Comment: Just use `"\\d+"` with `Matcher#find()` in a loop. See [How to extract numbers from a string and get an array of ints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367381/how-to-extract-numbers-from-a-string-and-get-an-array-of-ints)

Comment: So don't bother you for the rest of the string just \\d+

Comment: @remmaks Do you mean like this? `(?:\w+|\G(?!^))\h*,\h*([0-9]+)` https://regex101.com/r/n14Shg/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird yeah, that's nice, thanks.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think the OP was looking for a more specific way to get the matches. Do you agree if I reopen it and post it?

Comment: @remmaks Does [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2367418/3832970) work for you? Does it produce the result you want with all your test cases?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No, that is not enough for me unfortunately. But maybe my description was bad, but thanks anyway! Thefourbird's solution is what i was searching for.

Comment: [Your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61432785/in-java-with-regular-expressions-how-to-capture-numbers-from-a-string-with-unkn?noredirect=1#comment108673162_61432785) was misleading, please remove it. @Thefourthbird Please post.

Comment: So yes, the problem was that the first word in the string can contain numbers too, and i do not want to capture those. Sorry for bad description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match the leading word characters and make use of the `\G` anchor capturing the continuous digits after the comma.

*Pattern*

```
(?:\w+|\G(?!^))\h*,\h*([0-9]+)
```

*Explanation*

- `(?:` Non capture group
- `\w+` Match 1+ word chars
  -`|` or

  - `\G(?!^)` Assert postition at the end of previous match, not at the start
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `\h*,\h*` Match a comma between horizontal whitespace chars
- `([0-9]+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ digits

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/n14Shg/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/fySOKL)

In Java with double escaped backslashes:

```
String regex = "(?:\\w+|\\G(?!^))\\h*,\\h*([0-9]+)";
```

*Example code*

```
String regex = "(?:\\w+|\\G(?!^))\\h*,\\h*([0-9]+)";
String string = "sdfs6df -> no capture\n\n"
     + "fdg4dfg, 5 -> capture 5\n\n"
     + "fhhh3      ,     6,8    , 7 -> capture 6 8 and 7\n\n"
     + "asdasd1,4,2,7 -> capture 4 2 and 7";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Output

```
5
6
8
7
4
2
7
```