# Regex find number followed by any character (comma, dot, exclamation mark) (Java has

Tags: java, regex

I have the following strings where I would like to identify numbers, that can be sometimes followed by any character. For example:

- `Cats 10, Dogs 3?`
- `Cats 10 Dogs 3`
- `Cats 10. Dogs 3@`

I should be able to find 10 and 3 in each of these strings.

I tried
`s.matches("[0-9,.@!]+"))` but in this case I don't catch numbers not followed by special characters.

Comment: Maybe all you need is [How to extract numbers from a string and get an array of ints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367381/how-to-extract-numbers-from-a-string-and-get-an-array-of-ints?)

Answer (score -1):

Can you use the below?

```
s.matches("\d+")
```

Answer (score -1):

maybe try

```java
s.matches("[0-9].?");
```

. is any character

? is zero or more