# Java : Extracting Numbers from A given String

Tags: java

I have a String,

String a = Roll No 5 To 40;

I want to get that 5 and 40 values into Different variables, Like String b = 5 , c= 40

This values can Change to anything,like 50 TO 100 OR 10 TO 90 and so on Any Ideas How can I achieve that?

String a = Roll No 5 To 40;
To get 5, I converted a into String array, Iterated on it if matches("[0-9] then append in StringBuilder Will break if T comes In case of 40, With same String "[\d]+[\d] tried matching with this pattern

Thanks in Advance Akshay

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract numbers from a string and get an array of ints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367381/how-to-extract-numbers-from-a-string-and-get-an-array-of-ints)

Comment: One option would be to split the string on a regular expression that matches any non-empty amount of non-digits. That should leave you with precisely the items that are numbers. Those can then be converted using `Integer.valueOf` or similar: `for (String s : text.split("\\D+")) { System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(s)); }`

Answer (score 2):

It is convenient to use Stream API to convert the string into `int[]`:

```java
String a = "Roll No 5 To 40";


int[] ints = Arrays.stream(a.split("\\D+"))    // split the string by non-digits
                   .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())  // ignore empty strings
                   .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)// get int value
                   .toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ints));
```

Output

```
[5, 40]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the string format is always  "Roll No VAL1 To VAL2" you can do simple string manipulation:

```
String a = "Roll No 5 To 40";
int index_of_To = a.indexOf("To");
int index_of_No = a.indexOf("No");
String val1 = a.substring(index_of_No + 3,index_of_To).strip();
String val2 = a.substring(index_of_To + 3).strip();
```

Kindly note that this is a very ad hoc technique of doing this and is not very flexible.

Comment: and to get an `int` of that values, use `int num1 = Integer.parseInt(val1)`